# how to scroll to top of the iframe

Tags: javascript, html, angular, iframe, scroll

I'm using a different website(already active) into my webpage, but that website page is too big in height. So after restricting its height to 100vh (or some height). Scrolling down through the iframe is okay, but I need a floating '**scroll to top button**' for iframe which will bring the **iframe scroll to the top** (NOT the parent window scroll).

I have used this code in `.ts` file of **Angular**, and it worked for the parent window scroll, but NOT for `<iframe>`
P.S - I'm using Angular 7

```
scrollToTop(){
    window.scroll(0,0);
  }
```

`.html` code
`<button (click)="scrollToTop()">TOP</button>`
Thank you in advance.

**Update**: I have tried the following suggested way
`document.getElementById("myIframe").scroll(0,0);`
I'm able to print the innerHtml, that means getElementById is working fine, the issue is with `.scroll(0,0)` Had tried `.scrollTo(0,0)` & `.scrollBy(0,0)` too but results the same

Comment: Instead of `window` use the id of the iframe.

Comment: IF you don't have control over that website, make a call to their developers, share your `origin` and ask them to implement that feature if the parent window origin matches.

Comment: I had tried using the id of the iframe, but scrolling is not working

Answer (score 0):

Just do the same but replace the window with the iframe element:

```js
document.getElementById(<iFrameId>).scroll(0,0);
```

Comment: tried this, but the scroll is not working. See the update on the question section

Comment: simply because I think- scroll( ) is a method of the window object and not of the document object. Need a scroll( ) method for document object to work I think